# how to install python package on azure hdinsight pyspark3 kernel?

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I would like to install python 3.5 packages so they would be available in Jupyter notebook with pyspark3 kernel.

I've tried to run the following script action:

`#!/bin/bash
source /usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/activate py35
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda install -y keras tensorflow theano gensim`

but the packages get installed on python 2.7 and not in 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/conda install -y ...
```

or (if conda doesn't have the package)

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/pip install ...
```

Comment: Would you recommend I use a Script Action to execute this, or to SSH into the master/driver node on HDinsight?

Comment: Script action works ok for me (I use HDInsight as well)

Answer (score 1):

According to the help information of the command `conda help install`, there is a parameter `-n ENVIRONMENT` to do the package installation on a specified environment like `envs/py35`, the explaination as below.

> ```
> $ conda help install
> .......
> -n ENVIRONMENT, --name ENVIRONMENT
>                     Name of environment (in
>                     /home/sshuser/.conda/envs:/usr/bin/anaconda/envs).
> ```

So you can install these packages you want via the command as below.

```
sudo /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/conda install -y keras tensorflow theano gensim -n py35
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing using pip?

In some cases where you have both Python 2 and Python 3, you have to run pip3 instead of just pip to invoke pip for Python 3.